# User privileges in php(and multi user login form)

Tags: php, forms, authentication, privileges

i'm working on a school system(just to learn PHP) and i've already completed the administrator end but i want my login form to accept login data from the student,teacher and system administrator so that i can show a specific view of the system for each type of user. The code that is commented under the "if(isset($_POST["log"]))" is the one that i'm currently using for the administrator and it works perfectly(for my standards). Here is the code:

```
<?php
//Fazer login para admin e prof;ligar todas databases ao login;????
include("conect.php");
include("classes/class_est.php");
include("classes/class_login.php");
include("classes/class_admin.php");
include("classes/class_prof.php");
$user=(empty($_POST["username"])? "" :$_POST["username"]);
if(isset($_POST["log"])){
/*if(($user)&&($_POST["senha"]!=null)){
        $est=new admin();
        $est->login($user,$_POST["senha"],$_POST["tipo_user"]);
        }else{
            echo"<script>alert('Nome ou Senha Incorrecto')</script>";
        }
    }*/

switch($_POST["tipo_user"]){
        case"administrador":echo 'ighb';
            if(($_POST["username"])&&($_POST["senha"]!=null)){
            $admin=new admin();
            $admin->login($_POST["username"],$_POST["senha"],$_POST["tipo_user"]);
            }else{
            echo"<script>alert('Nome ou Senha Incorrectos')</script>";
        }
            ;
         break;
        case"estudante":
            if(($_POST["username"])&&($_POST["senha"]!=null)){
            $est=new est();
            $est->login($_POST["username"],$_POST["senha"],$_POST["tipo_user"]);
            }else{
            echo"<script>alert('Nome ou Senha Incorrectos')</script>";
        };
        break;
        case"professor":
            if(($_POST["username"] && $_POST["senha"])!=null){
                $prof=new prof();
                $prof=login($_POST["username"],$_POST["senha"],$_POST["tipo_user"]);
            }else{
                echo"<script>alert('Nome ou Senha Incorrectos')</script>";
            };
            break;
        default;break;
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos/forms.css"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    </head>
<body>
    <center>
        <div id="login">
            <div id="black_m"><img src="estilos/imagens/black_mamba_logo.png"/></div>
        <table>
        <form method="POST">
            <tr><td>Tipo de usuário:</td><td><?php $listar=new login;$listar->list_tipo()?></td><td><span>(Para Alpha)</span></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Username: </td><td><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Insira o nome de usuário" id="texto"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Senha: </td><td><input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Insira a senha" id="texto"/><td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="submit" name="log" value="ENTRAR" id="texto"/></tr>
        </form>
    </table>
    </div>
    </center>
</body>`
```

Comment: Your display system shouldn't be coupled with your login system.  The login system should process logins.  After login, you should have a user type related to that user so your system knows what view to render for that user.

Answer (score 2):

Are you familiar with using a database? Storing username,password and access_levels inside a users table of a database might be the best option for you. OTherwise, you will have to hard-code the user's access values in your script. If you do this, you can create a switch defining their privilege values like:

```
$username=$_POST['user'];
switch $username {
  case "supercool_admin":
  $access_level="admin";
break;
  case "supercool_student":
  $access_level="student";
break;
  case "supercool_teacher":
  $access_level="teacher";
break;
  default:
  $access_level="none";
}
```

Then when you are displaying contents, you would reference the access_level as either an if statement, or another switch.

eg:

```
if($access_level=="admin") {
 //DISPLAY ADMIN CONTENTS
} elseif ($access_level=="teacher") {
 //DISPLAY TEACHER CONTENTS
} elseif ($access_level=="student") {
 //DISPLAY STUDENT CONTENTS
} else {
  echo "YOU DO NOT HAVE PERMISSION TO VIEW THESE CONTENTS";
}
```

I can also suggest not using post values to do your lookups, instead use the post values to authenticate against either a database, or in your case, inside the switch. Once authenticated and their access_level is defined, store those values in a session and reference that instead.